# Division gives random numbers in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, division, tradingview-api

Please find the code snippet below. I try to declare few variables, assign value and then divide certain numbers. But the result is completely random.

I put the values of the variables into a table for debugging but I cannot understand what the problem could be. I mean all the values assigned to the variables are correct but the result of the division is rather random. (see attached screenshots)

For testing I used 1000 USD for starting capital, so the result should be 500/price, in case of BTC around 0,025 (@20K), in case of ADA around 10 000-11 000 (@0.45-0.50). [Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H58kg.jpg) [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt87V.jpg)

```
varip float startingCapital = input.float(defval=1000.0, title="Starting capital", minval=15)
varip float StartingBaseSize = na
varip float StartingCurrencySize = na
varip float BasePrice = na
varip float CurrencyPrice = na

BasePrice := request.security(syminfo.basecurrency + "USDT", "D", close)
CurrencyPrice := request.security(syminfo.currency + "USDT", "D", close)

if syminfo.currency == "USDT" or syminfo.currency == "USD"
    CurrencyPrice := 1.0

if na(StartingBaseSize) == true
    StartingBaseSize := (startingCapital/BasePrice)/2
if na(StartingCurrencySize) == true
    StartingCurrencySize := (startingCapital/CurrencyPrice)/2
```

Comment: 500/price because I split the starting capital like if I would start pure market making.

Comment: This is the cell where I plot the result of the calculations:

`code`
table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 3, text = "50% Starting capital: " + str.tostring(startingCapital/2) + " USD"
     + "\nStarting base: " + str.tostring(StartingBaseSize) + " " + str.tostring(syminfo.basecurrency)
     + "\nActual baseprice: " + str.tostring(BasePrice)
     + "\nBase * price: " + str.tostring(StartingBaseSize*BasePrice))

Comment: If I hardcode an exact number to the code above instead of "BasePrice" variable, the calculation is correct. But as I want to do position sizing later I will need the actual prices.

Comment: For some reason request.security("BINANCE:" + syminfo.basecurrency + "USDT", "D", close) does not give the today's price. That's the bug.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the request.security comes back with an array and in that array at the last index is the most current close value.

```
temp = request.security_lower_tf("BTCUSD", "60", close)
BasePrice := array.get(temp, array.size(temp)-1)
```